# Apache Superset's Architecture

Tags: architecture, apache-superset

I want to know the architecture of the Apache Superset project. I would love something like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rSjL.jpg)

Where can I find it? Or can anybody create one?

Answer (score 0):

Joseph Machado created this helpful diagram of Superset's architecture!

https://www.startdataengineering.com/images/apache-superset-tutorial/ss_arch.png